# OpenGL Multiple VBOs for 1 VAO

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine

I am working on heightmap terrain for my game engine project, and noticed that I had most of the same code being put into a VAO for each terrain chunk, so a lot of duplicate data. I have already been using the same few LOD Index Buffers for these chunks, and was wondering if I could make 1 VAO with the X and Z positions, and the texture coordinates, then have a VBO the chunk handles with the rest of my data? So I have 1 common VAO with the grid layout and texture coordinates, then I have 1 VBO per chunk with height, and the 3 constants I need to calculate normal, tangent, and bitangents. Is this possible, and if so, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have one texture for the height map or multiple textures?

Comment: A VBO can be shared by more than one VAO if that is what you are asking. Assuming a chunk is the same as a tile, a rectangular block of terrain, yes you could reuse the XZ and texture coords for each chunk. (Although if they are a rectangular regular grid, it could be even easier to generate them automatically within the shader.)

VAOs are fairly "lightweight" objects, just a list of VBO pointers/id numbers with the attribute index and some layout info (2/3/4 per vert, int/float) so reuse should be faster and smaller than duplicating VBOs

Comment: @HughFisher no, what I meant is 1 VAO with the XZ and texture coords, then a seperate VBO with the chunk specific data i need. I guess I can just use a VAO per chunk if that is the case though, I was just wondering because I wanted to bind the VAO, then loop through the chunks, as binding a VAO is a little pricey, is it not?

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about the concepts. VAOs don't contain vertex data, VBOs do. VAOs are just state bundles containing vertex attribute setup state.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Right, But I use LWJGL with java, and I was pretty sure that when binding a VAO with LWJGL it does some nutty checks cause LWJGL doesnt do enough(sarcasm). Though worse is when the native code crashes without an error, it pulled that one on me a few weeks ago

Comment: If you're using a VAO, it has to contain all the VBOs you want to draw. And in OpenGL 4, you MUST have a VAO. Binding a VAO will be faster than setting up all the attrib arrays yourself, and faster than drawing or copying data.